# Cannot create webrtc call using sip.js

Tags: sip, freeswitch, sip-server

I am not able to create a Webrtc call using sip.js on FreeSWITCH. I believe there are some issues with Freeswitch configuration, but I'm not able to figure out where the issue is and how to figure it out.
Any help would be highly appreciated. I've attached my console log:

```
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | SessionDescriptionHandlerOptions: {"constraints":{},"peerConnectionOptions":{}}
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | initPeerConnection
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | New peer connection created
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | acquiring local media
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6799202;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=taqhpgkssv
To: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=10ga65Ue7mQee
Call-ID: fi260t6dtqnqn0ptskor9r
CSeq: 2907 REGISTER
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="XYZ.com", nonce="15500d94-ee66-11e8-b1ab-4361709f15e6", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

REGISTER sip:XYZ.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8071543
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=taqhpgkssv
Call-ID: fi260t6dtqnqn0ptskor9r
CSeq: 2908 REGISTER
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="1002", realm="XYZ.com", nonce="15500d94-ee66-11e8-b1ab-4361709f15e6", uri="sip:XYZ.com", response="5c9ea6e954ab46bce7d4e47c32ca8412", qop=auth, cnonce="3r55378pf6n7", nc=00000001
Contact: <sip:5l366f2t@jttr6lobgmns.invalid;transport=ws>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:e6e84559-2720-4d41-ad03-146b793010e2>";expires=600
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,REFER
Supported: path, gruu, outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.11.6
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:23 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8071543;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=taqhpgkssv
To: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=299270cj4XD1S
Call-ID: fi260t6dtqnqn0ptskor9r
CSeq: 2908 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:5l366f2t@jttr6lobgmns.invalid;transport=ws>;expires=600
Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 14:51:24 GMT
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | acquired local media streams
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | RTCIceGatheringState changed: gathering
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:2174247646 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.3.199 49154 typ host generation 0 ufrag MAkZ network-cost 999
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:2174247646 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.3.199 49156 typ host generation 0 ufrag MAkZ network-cost 999
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 146.4.10.10 49156 typ srflx raddr 192.168.3.199 rport 49156 generation 0 ufrag MAkZ network-cost 999
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 146.4.10.10 49154 typ srflx raddr 192.168.3.199 rport 49154 generation 0 ufrag MAkZ network-cost 999
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | RTCIceGatheringState changed: complete
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:1001@XYZ.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
Contact: <sip:5l366f2t@jttr6lobgmns.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,REFER
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.11.6
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 5285

v=0
o=- 153243296618550758 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf
m=audio 49154 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 146.4.10.10
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2174247646 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.3.199 49154 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999
a=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 146.4.10.10 49154 typ srflx raddr 192.168.3.199 rport 49154 generation 0 network-cost 999
a=ice-ufrag:MAkZ
a=ice-pwd:bWXLDz7c+92/dd8QoZStRG2O
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D9:03:E8:8E:59:9C:F9:C7:F1:97:1C:2E:8B:9D:AA:8B:22:72:79:0A:DA:20:F5:15:0B:92:01:0D:90:96:2E:BC
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:4246339017 cname:S6yAd62x0R59DnAa
a=ssrc:4246339017 msid:KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf ff315b12-5a25-40df-bd9c-63d5fa8839dd
a=ssrc:4246339017 mslabel:KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf
a=ssrc:4246339017 label:ff315b12-5a25-40df-bd9c-63d5fa8839dd
m=video 49156 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114
c=IN IP4 146.4.10.10
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2174247646 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.3.199 49156 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999
a=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 146.4.10.10 49156 typ srflx raddr 192.168.3.199 rport 49156 generation 0 network-cost 999
a=ice-ufrag:MAkZ
a=ice-pwd:bWXLDz7c+92/dd8QoZStRG2O
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D9:03:E8:8E:59:9C:F9:C7:F1:97:1C:2E:8B:9D:AA:8B:22:72:79:0A:DA:20:F5:15:0B:92:01:0D:90:96:2E:BC
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0032
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 red/90000
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 2475933144 456734105
a=ssrc:2475933144 cname:S6yAd62x0R59DnAa
a=ssrc:2475933144 msid:KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf 2c31a0cb-b321-42e0-891b-d077b29416ce
a=ssrc:2475933144 mslabel:KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf
a=ssrc:2475933144 label:2c31a0cb-b321-42e0-891b-d077b29416ce
a=ssrc:456734105 cname:S6yAd62x0R59DnAa
a=ssrc:456734105 msid:KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf 2c31a0cb-b321-42e0-891b-d077b29416ce
a=ssrc:456734105 mslabel:KhwBRkNdQhKG8uBiFShsdLtQDpQghHNP4DCf
a=ssrc:456734105 label:2c31a0cb-b321-42e0-891b-d077b29416ce


sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | ICE candidate gathering complete
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp>
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Accept: application/sdp
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
Content-Length: 0
Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:dv7k2aea@XYZ.com>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:26 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.dialog | new UAC dialog created with status EARLY
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:31 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp>
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1611
Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:dv7k2aea@XYZ.com>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1542875692 1542875693 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 21.135.71.140
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
m=audio 22600 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22600 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=ice-ufrag:sLb4c6Ntf3hGXrOU
a=ice-pwd:fWOE8ym4ReEccY5uz6pC33V8
a=candidate:7384996702 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 22600 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
a=ssrc:2482680622 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:2482680622 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh a0
a=ssrc:2482680622 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:2482680622 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kha0
m=video 21928 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:21928 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=ssrc:1711252375 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:1711252375 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh v0
a=ssrc:1711252375 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:1711252375 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3khv0
a=ice-ufrag:yysGP93QpcAYPz41
a=ice-pwd:pNHITqOLemWhNzScXbJCaCjq
a=candidate:0811010037 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 21928 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates


sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:31 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.dialog | dialog d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg9ktrgj6ju04UvmBQeSyFt6g  changed to CONFIRMED state
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:31 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | track added
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:36 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | track added
sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5822553
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 ACK
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.11.6
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp>
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1611
Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:dv7k2aea@XYZ.com>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1542875692 1542875693 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 21.135.71.140
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
m=audio 22600 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22600 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=ice-ufrag:sLb4c6Ntf3hGXrOU
a=ice-pwd:fWOE8ym4ReEccY5uz6pC33V8
a=candidate:7384996702 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 22600 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
a=ssrc:2482680622 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:2482680622 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh a0
a=ssrc:2482680622 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:2482680622 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kha0
m=video 21928 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:21928 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=ssrc:1711252375 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:1711252375 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh v0
a=ssrc:1711252375 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:1711252375 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3khv0
a=ice-ufrag:yysGP93QpcAYPz41
a=ice-pwd:pNHITqOLemWhNzScXbJCaCjq
a=candidate:0811010037 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 21928 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates


sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5822553
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 ACK
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.11.6
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp>
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1611
Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:dv7k2aea@XYZ.com>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1542875692 1542875693 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 21.135.71.140
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
m=audio 22600 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22600 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=ice-ufrag:sLb4c6Ntf3hGXrOU
a=ice-pwd:fWOE8ym4ReEccY5uz6pC33V8
a=candidate:7384996702 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 22600 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
a=ssrc:2482680622 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:2482680622 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh a0
a=ssrc:2482680622 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:2482680622 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kha0
m=video 21928 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:21928 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=ssrc:1711252375 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:1711252375 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh v0
a=ssrc:1711252375 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:1711252375 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3khv0
a=ice-ufrag:yysGP93QpcAYPz41
a=ice-pwd:pNHITqOLemWhNzScXbJCaCjq
a=candidate:0811010037 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 21928 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates


sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5822553
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 ACK
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.11.6
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9014939;received=146.4.10.10;rport=53279
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp>
User-Agent: UCP SIP
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, PRACK, NOTIFY
Supported: precondition, 100rel, timer, path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1611
Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:dv7k2aea@XYZ.com>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1542875692 1542875693 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 21.135.71.140
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
m=audio 22600 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22600 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=ice-ufrag:sLb4c6Ntf3hGXrOU
a=ice-pwd:fWOE8ym4ReEccY5uz6pC33V8
a=candidate:7384996702 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 22600 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
a=ssrc:2482680622 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:2482680622 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh a0
a=ssrc:2482680622 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:2482680622 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kha0
m=video 21928 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:31:63:0A:35:84:28:91:9E:94:0F:6A:5A:E2:99:1A:DC:AA:36:4C:86:81:C7:EE:72:EB:0D:F4:A8:87:2E:AA
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:21928 IN IP4 21.135.71.140
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=ssrc:1711252375 cname:6Xi4zlTR5s2Kv7t2
a=ssrc:1711252375 msid:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh v0
a=ssrc:1711252375 mslabel:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3kh
a=ssrc:1711252375 label:PcNb7LcZsUJkOdfTGusiMA5SriqXB3khv0
a=ice-ufrag:yysGP93QpcAYPz41
a=ice-pwd:pNHITqOLemWhNzScXbJCaCjq
a=candidate:0811010037 1 udp 659136 21.135.71.140 21928 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates


sip-0.11.6.js:516 Thu Nov 22 2018 15:51:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:1001@21.135.71.140:5070;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS jttr6lobgmns.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5822553
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@XYZ.com>;tag=4UvmBQeSyFt6g
From: <sip:1002@XYZ.com>;tag=9ktrgj6ju0
Call-ID: d1gsfqrmq28p029ntjsg
CSeq: 1865 ACK
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.11.6
Content-Length: 0
```